# Stop Visual Studio from adding namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

We're writing a framework in C# using the Unity Engine for easy prototyping. Everything in the framework is decoupled from Unity except for special wrapper classes. We use our own types and namespaces along with #if directives to achieve this.

For some reason, Visual Studio keeps automatically adding "using" directives to the top of scripts when we type class or method names from other libraries. It clutters our code and creates compatibility issues + naming collisions if we don't remove them.

Normally I wouldn't mind this feature, but it's a time sink as I have to search through the source to remove any auto-included lines.

I've searched the options but can't find a solution. It surely has to do with intellisense.

Is there a way to turn this feature off or maybe tweak it in a way that would benefit us?

Many thanks,

Loui

Comment: Yes that fixed the issue right away. Thank you very much.